# Foward Weblogic port on Virtualbox

Tags: weblogic, port, virtualbox

I try to forward Weblogic port on VirtualBox, but it's not work ...

In VirtualBox :

[image]

With a tomcat , I have not had a problem (Port 8080).

Can someone help me?

Regards.

Comment: I use Virtualbox with this same setting and it works for me. Are sure that the VM is listening on 7001 and nothing in the host is already using 7001?